# Error getting while cloning from BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to clone repository from BitBucket in SourceCode and command prompt as well. But getting the below error related to some certification file.

error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: C:/Users/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/usr/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

I am not able to find the curl-ca-bundle.crt file in the above location, when i search in my machine. could some one please let me know the solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by pasting the curl-ca-bundle.crt file in the location at which it is missing. And I took this certification file from another machine,  where I can able to access the repository.